# How to SWITCH Power Apps Data Connection in Canvas App

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I have a canvas app that uses a SQL Server Data Source connection. In my Power Apps environment, I have created a second SQL Server Data Source connction. How do I update my canvas app to use the second SQL Connection instead of the original one it was imported with?

I would like to retain the two connections in my environment so that I can point to different SQL Servers by updating the connection used. The schema of the data is the same between connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to follow the below steps:

1. Open the PowerApps with edit:
   [image]
2. Navigate to the connections and add the new connector for your second SQL source:
   [image]
3. Both connectors will be available now. Depending on how your App is setup, you now re-point formulas where the initial SQL connector is referenced to the second source.